# parse simple-JSONObject in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

i want to simple parse it to jsonObject .
the resone way is this i just want to manage order of the object

```
    try {
        { JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();                 
  ContainerFactory containerFactory = new ContainerFactory(){
    public List creatArrayContainer() {                       
return new LinkedList();   }
       public Map createObjectContainer() {             
          return new LinkedHashMap();    }    };
   json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(responce, containerFactory);
```

this is link where my question [is](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/issues/detail?id=78) 
i m using simple jsonObject

Answer (score 0):

Better use `Jackson` to simplify your work....

**See this link:**

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: i couldn't use any other object because i just want to manage the same order and as it comes from api. and i have implemant all the complex using JsonObject.. i couldn't to back now .i just need jsonObject

Comment: @In what form are you getting the JSON...is it an `JSONArray or just JSONObject`